# Missing Authentication Auth0 for /api/v2/users/{id}

Tags: javascript, axios, auth0

I have got the token from hitting the end point `/oauth/token` and passed it through on postman to `/api/v2/users/{id}` through the headers like so

```
{Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
```

and on postman it works just fine and gives me back the user. However when I do it in my application I get back a 401 error. I am using axios and passing the token like so.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .post('https://taustin.auth0.com/oauth/token', body, headers)
      .then(res => {
        resolve(res.data.access_token);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
```

Above is the generateToken function.

```
generateToken()
          .then(token => {
            const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
            console.log(token); //token is valid here
            axios
              .get(
                `https://taustin.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${profile.sub}`,
                headers
              )
              .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
              });
          })
```

In the catch block I get the 401 unauth error and message. I'm not sure what I'm doing different from postman vs my application, but I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are the rest of the request headers the same? Content-type, Accept, maybe Referer and Origin?

Comment: Can you show the entire flow of 1) getting token 2) passing token? There might be something in between that is causing issues

Comment: @GaborLengyel Yes the headers are the same. Hunter an edit will be made

Comment: @TaylorAustin try wrapping headers in an object literal, I believe that all of the options to GET have to be passed as a single object: `axios.get(URL, { headers })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing headers as you should

you should be doing something like this:

```
const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
axios
 .get(
   `https://taustin.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${profile.sub}`,
   headers: headers
 ).then().catch()
```

or try like this

```
axios
 .get(
   `https://taustin.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${profile.sub}`,
   headers: {`Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
 ).then().catch()
```

Hope these will help you please reply if you need anymore help.

Comment: I completely forgot axios does that with get, thank you!

Comment: That's totally fine. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure whether you have Axios setup correctly, please take a look at [this react sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/react-redux-embedded-login/blob/master/src/actions/password/index.js#L32) (wrote a few months ago but should still be relevant).

If your issue is not with how you are shaping your Axios request, but rather with something else, please check the access token. For instance, actually use the access token you are using in your app, and try that same access token via Postman. If your access token is not `opaque`, but rather a JWT access tokent, then check the `audience` value. It should conform to `https://taustin.auth0.com/userinfo/`.

Finally, if postman is working, you could also try the generate code snippet option, and export a working sample using `request` (node.js). Then if that works, modify to Axios along the same lines. Feel free to post questions in comments below.